# Why to pass 3 dots in the imshow() for plotting hsv?

Tags: matplotlib, image-processing, data-visualization, data-science, scikit-image

I was going through some video and some files, there I got stuck up with a code as written below:

```
im_hsv = color.rgb2hsv(im)

plt.gray()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.subplot(221), plt.imshow(im_hsv[...,0]), plt.title('h', size=20), plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(222), plt.imshow(im_hsv[...,1]), plt.title('s', size=20), plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(223), plt.imshow(im_hsv[...,2]), plt.title('v', size=20), plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(224), plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

In 3rd - 5th line of code, why there is three dots followed by 0?
Without those dots I was getting a single vertical line.

Comment: `...` means ignoring all the previous dimension. So `im_hsv[...,0]` is equivalent to `im_hsv[:,:,0]`.

Comment: You can use the ellipsis (three dots) in Numpy to mean *"however many channels/dimensions there are before (or after) the bits I do choose to use."*

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for clearing the doubt.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 2):

`...` notation is known as Python Ellipsis object. As you try to plot h, s and v channels separately and image consists of 3 dimensions, dimensions should be indicated by using ':' for each one of them. Instead, you can simply use Ellipsis object. `im_hsv[...,0]` equals to `im_hsv[:,:,0]`. It could seem unnecessary but when you work with more than 3 dimensions, it is useful and increases the readability as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That is really helpful.